# does argparse not work with # characters?

Tags: python, argparse

I  have this script:

```
#!/bin/python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When attempting to run this script, eg
`./test.py -i #` it responds with:

```
usage: test.py [-h] -i INPUT
test.py: error: argument -i/--input: expected one argument
```

On: `python 3.10.2`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably starting a comment in your shell with the `#`
character. Use `'#'`.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass that? 
I dont want to have to do `\#` or `'#'` all the time.

Comment: @bendn depends on the shell you're using

Comment: im using bash: `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @bendn no idea, maybe ask a new question with bash tag